# How to Check the Toggle State of Mobile Data using BroadCast Receiver?

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I want to turn off the mobile data if my app is connected to wifi device without internet connection.

If its not possible to turn off mobile data then i want to show alert dialog that tells user to turn off the mobile data.
Below code i am using , help me to check the state of wifi Connection.

please help me out.

```
public boolean broadcastingInitialization() {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) sContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        onWifi = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int extraWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
                Log.v("Mobile DATA  STATE", String.valueOf(connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState()));

                switch (extraWifiState) {
                    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                        Log.d("Wifi:", "WIFI STATE DISABLED");
                        wifiState = "DISABLED";
                        wifiAlertInit(); //show the wifi alert dialog if wifi state is disabled
                        alert.show();
                        break;
                    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                        Log.d("Wifi:", "WIFI STATE ENABLED");
                        if (connMgr != null) {
                            mMobileData = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                            Log.v("MOBILE DATA:", String.valueOf(mMobileData.getExtraInfo()));
                        }
                        if (mMobileData.getExtraInfo() != null) {
                            MobileDataAlertInit(); // show the Mobile data alert box if both wifi and mobile is on at same time
                            alert.show();
                        }
                        if (mMobileData.getExtraInfo() == null) {
                            alert.dismiss();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        if (connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getExtraInfo() == null && connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()) {
            getInitIPAddress(sActivity); // get IP address only when WIFI STATE is ENABLED
            return true;
        }
        getApplication().registerReceiver(onWifi, filter);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? What isn't working? Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: I want to know the state of the toggle button of mobile data if its on or off .